# Pull-back operation preserves elementary set operations

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding how to show Pull-back preserves elementary operations.

Actually I am kind of confused about "Pull-back" because it seems to be same thing as inverse mapping, but I am kind of confused as I only heard about "Pull-back" for the first time as I am reading a notes on measure theory, it is on Page 3 at the bottom of the page
https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/measurable_spaces.pdf.

My question is this:

For a function $f: S \rightarrow T$ and subsets $A \subseteq S, B \subseteq T$, we define the Pull-back as $f^{-1}(B)$ of $B \subseteq T$ as $f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in S : f(x) \in B \} \subseteq S$

Show that the pull-back operation preserves the elementary set operations, i.e., for $f: S \rightarrow T$, and $B$, $\{B_N\}_{n \in N} \subseteq T$, we have the following hold:

1. $f^{-1}(T) = S, f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$

My question is can I prove $f^{-1}(T) = S$ by just showing the left is subset of the right, and the right is subset of the left?

Because then by definition, $f^{-1}(T)$ is a subset of $S$, i.e. $f^{-1}(T) \subseteq S$ (because I can just substitute $T$ as $B$ into the above definition of "pull-back"). So if it is correct, then the "left is a subset of the right" is satisfied.

Then to show the right is a subset of the left. Say let x be an element in $S$, i.e. $x \in S$, then there exists a $t \in T$ such that $f(x) = t \in T$, and hence $x \in f^{-1}(T)$ as $f^{-1}(T)$ is a set of elements (say $s$) of $S$ such that $f(s) \in T$. So the right hand side is a subset of the left hand side, if the proof is correct.

My question is, is the above correct? Because I have encountered something similar when I was learning introductory analysis when I was trying to prove something involving inverse mapping, 1-1 function, etc.

But I am not sure if I understand pull-back correctly as it seems that (at least based on notation and symbol) pull-back is kind of like inverse mapping or inverse function?

Could someone give some comments or explanations to clarify my confusion?

Also my other question is: is $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ another property that the "pull-back" has to satisfy?

Thank you for your time and input.